# JSON->String in python

Tags: python, json

Say I get this line of JSON

```
[{u'status': u'active', u'due_date': None, u'group': u'later', u'task_id': 73286}]
```

How can I convert those separate values to strings? So I can say

```
Print Status
```

And it returns

```
active
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That is NOT a "line of JSON" as received from an external source. It looks like the result of `json.loads(external_JSON_string)`. Also `Print Status` won't work; you mean `print status`.

```
>>> result = [{u'status': u'active', u'due_date': None, u'group': u'later', u'task_id': 73286}]
>>> print result[0]['status']
active
```

This is what a "line of JSON" looks like:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(result)
'[{"status": "active", "due_date": null, "group": "later", "task_id": 73286}]'
>>>
```

EDIT: If using Python 2.5, use `import simplejson as json` instead of `import json`. Make your code a bit more future-proof by doing this:

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
```

Comment: So if what he is showing isn't a line of JSON - then what does one use to stringify that? Is that already a string? Is there something that needs to be done to it to treat it as a string (i.e. "un-unicode" it for example)?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, that ain't JSON as was already pointed out - it's python already.

I think you want the keys of the dict automatically transform into local variables. This would be a **really bad idea**, although in theory, it's possible using `locals ()`:

```
result = [{u'status': u'active', u'due_date': None, u'group': u'later', u'task_id': 73286}]
for k, v in result[0].items():
    locals() [k] = v
print status # prints active
```

Some problems:

- Your keys might overwrite some existing local variables
- Keys might be unicode, how would you access the variable names?

Also, as stated in the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals), locals () should not be modified.

In short: do it like this:

```
print result[0]['status']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import simplejson
_dict = simplejson.loads(json_data)
for entry in _dict:
# loop over list
    print entry.get('status','Failure')
    # Find key in dict/entry
```

Comment: I get this error:   File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 385, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 402, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer